# I migrate defaults command to PlistBuddy, and it outputs exact same plist, but not working right

Tags: macos, applescript, plist, default

## Situation

I wrote many defaults command here, which is to set applications on dock.

https://github.com/ryuta69/dotfiles/blob/master/macos/lib/dockitem.applescript

Then, I migrate them to PlistBuddy below.

https://github.com/ryuta69/dotfiles/blob/master/macos/lib/dockitem.zsh

They generate persistent-apps in com.apple.dock. defaults command works fine, and it sets Applications on dock.

However, PlistBuddy one doesn't work, it doesn't set any apps on dock, even though persistent-apps in com.apple.dock are same.

```sh
osascript dockitem.applescript
defaults read com.apple.dock > a.txt

zsh dockitem.zsh
defaults read com.apple.dock > b.txt

diff a.txt b.txt
# there is no difference
```

I also did `Killall Dock` (It's in the script).

Is there any steps I forgot to do with PlistBuddy? I couldn't find any information except `Killall Dock`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it.
I need to `killall cfprefsd` before `killall Dock`.

preferences are cached, and defaults will remove cache, but PlistBuddy doesn't. I need to kill it.